# How can I convert .img (disk image) to .jpg?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, diskimage

I have many .img(disk image) files. they are images and need to be
converted to .jpg format.
I tried to implement it in Python. it outputs `ValueError: embedded null byte`
What do I missing?

```
from PIL import Image

rawData  = open('./1990016479_0001.img', 'rb').read()
pil_img = Image.open(rawData)
pil_img.save('./1990016479_0001.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Example　Image (.img  disk image)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XYqQJTrbT2Y-4hhrLYKR3kuRIoxufy0o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just because there's "image" in the name does not mean they're actual _images_, you know, pictures. What are you trying to do, exactly? What's in those disk images?

Comment: thank you for your response.  I am trying to extract image in the disk images.  It contains one image file.

Answer (score 2):

Image files are not pictures and as such they cannot be converted to pictures such as .jpg files.

> .img refers to binary files with the .img filename extension that
> store raw disk images of floppy disks, hard drives, and optical discs
> or a bitmap image – .img.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)

To be a little more specific, I believe you are referring to binary disk images, because you specified (.img disk image).

Also, the binary file you linked doesn't look like a bitmap. The linux `file` utility didn't recognize it and neither did imagemagick.

Comment: thank you for your response. I see.  If  the ```file``` utility cannot recognize it  then, is it impossible to extract image in the disk images?

Comment: @SKG At least I don't know how to mount / open that file, it could be that someone else has some way to open or to get more informatioin about the file but I don't, sorry!